# Display buttons In the certain format using ng-repeat

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using angularjs and bootstrap3. I have array of array of objects and I need to display it in the UI like below,

```
sample = [
  {
    "id": 12,
    "title": "title2",
    "description": "description2_for the second"
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "title": "title3",
    "description": "description3"
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "title": "title4",
    "description": "description4"
  },
  {
    "id": 18,
    "title": "title5",
    "description": "description5"
  },
  {
    "id": 19,
    "title": "title6",
    "description": "description6"
  },
  {
    "id": 20,
    "title": "title7",
    "description": "description7"
  },
  {
    "id": 21,
    "title": "title8",
    "description": "description8"
  },
  {
    "id": 22,
    "title": "title9",
    "description": "description9"
  }
]
```

my code ng-repeat look like,

```
<div class="editor-preview">
  <div class="row" >
    <div class="col-md-4 " ng-repeat-start="i in sample track by $index">
      <div class="tooltip"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-round-lg btn-lg">{{i.title}}</button>
        <span class="tooltiptext">{{i.description}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix" ng-if="($index+1)%3==0"></div>
    <div ng-repeat-end=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From the above code, UI is looking like below image.

[image]

But, I want to show the UI like the below image and 3 buttons per row

[image]

How to show the UI like above image in bootstrap css dynamically for alternative rows too

Comment: Can you provide a code example on plunker or similar?

Comment: You want code example like? you need what is the content in ng-repeat ?

Comment: What you can do is create two different lists from the main list, and apply different css classes on them to get different result.

Comment: @Michael created a small fiddle for you. please check here https://jsfiddle.net/mehbub/mnatc2b6/1/

Comment: @Michael Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mehbub/mnatc2b6/3/

Comment: Http://jsfiddle.net/mnatc2b6/9/ is this what you want to achive? Take a look on the last 2 css rules on li tag. And u removed display inline before. (I did it on mobile, cant check it fully)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `list-inline` for this layout:
http://jsfiddle.net/hstppbj8/804/

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="sample">
  <div class="editor-preview-testimonials">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <ul class="list-inline text-center">
          <li ng-repeat="i in sample track by $index"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
     {{i.title}}<span class="tooltiptext"> {{i.description}}</span>
      </button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix" ng-if="($index+1)%3==0"></div>
      <div ng-repeat-end=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul li {
  margin: 4px 0; /*For spacing between li*/
}
```

Resize the jsfiddle window to see the layout properly.

Comment: But, I should show 3 buttons per row, even they are 8 or 9

Comment: @user6250770 You can use ng-switch for that. You will need to change the layout as per the condition

Comment: Please check this fiddle and can u please add the snippet here https://jsfiddle.net/mehbub/mnatc2b6/1/

Answer (score 0):

try to have the text for the content to be different ( some are longer, some are much longer ) for each of the button. It should be prolonged as the class ".btn" css has {display: inline-block} in them. Then make sure there is a wrapper around these buttons and make them { text-align: center }

Answer (score 0):

In angular 1 ng-repeat has been used. But in ng-5 this syntax has been changed with ng-for. I would suggest you to please use the ng-for to use the angular loop. in that case Your code will be like the following.

```
<div ng-controller="sample">
  <div class="editor-preview-testimonials">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <ul class="list-inline text-center">
          <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index""><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
    <span class="tooltiptext">  {{i}} {{description}}</span>
      </button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix" ng-if="($index+1)%3==0"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: am using angular 1.x only